# How to get the currently installed Joomla! Version in PHP

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-4.x, versions

For one of my extensions i need a switch statement if the Joomla! Version is 3.x or 4. (in fact i have to call the Articles Model in different way for J4) - but how can i get the actual installed Joomla! Version by PHP (inside my helper)?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Might these can help? https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Version.html , https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/JVersion/getShortVersion/php-jversion-getshortversion-method-examples.html , https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/8862fff0e13f4759bd2bf03dec335284e11c6fb9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JVERSION` constant. It holds the value returned by `Joomla\CMS\Version::getShortVersion()`.